# How do I set the built in 'Users' to use a datasource using loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to set the built in `user` model to use a MySQL server for data storage.  But I am not sure how to migrate over,

I have this snippet in model-config.js:

```
"User": {
  "dataSource": "db"
},
"AccessToken": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"ACL": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"RoleMapping": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
},
"Role": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
}
```

Now I would assume I set the datasource to a user datasource I created for the `User`.  How do I got about the proper schema, and what about these other default models?

Answer (score 1):

Change the the dataSource property's value to the name of your MySQL datasource.

```
...
"User": {
  "dataSource": "mySqlDs" //name of your data source
}
...
```

Comment: What about schema, I have done that, and now my request to create a user times out.

Comment: Try a basic example. Scaffold a new loopback project via `slc loopback`, add the MySQL connector, add the MySQL data source to `datasources.json`, then create a boot script that adds a user to the database and inspect your database schema.